# Calling google cloud endpoint api from another google app engine web application servlet java

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

I have a google cloud endpoint api application which i want to call it from another google app engine web application, say from a servlet. The cloud endpoint api is not secured.

I tried looking for examples but could not find one. I see example related to Android client.
When tried using URLConnection it does not work, am not sure whether am doing correctly as well,  sample codes or pointers will be of great help. I also checked the logs of cloud endpoint api to see if any requests are coming through, but i don't see any errors in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this as well, although with authentication. You can use the Jar generated by the endpoint API at MyAPI/build/libs/MyAPI-v1-SNAPSHOT.jar, just as you might in Android.

Once you depend on that JAR, your code to build an API client should look something like that below. Mine is using OAuth authentication with a service account, which I'll leave in there because it was the more complicated part which you might eventually need. But without authentication you should just be able to set the credential to null.

```java
    HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(EMAIL_SCOPE);
    String SERVICE_ACCCOUNT_ID = "my-account-id@my-app.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
    String CREDENTIAL_FILE = "WEB-INF/my-file.p12";

    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCCOUNT_ID)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(CREDENTIAL_FILE))
            .build();

    MyAPI.Builder builder = new MyAPI.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT,
            JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            // options for running against local devappserver
            // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
            // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
            .setRootUrl("http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/")
            //  .setRootUrl("https://my-appengine-url.appspot.com/_ah/api")

    MyAPI myAPI = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use URLConnection for making endpoint calls from App Engine. Use `FetchURL` instead. If you set `doNotFollowRedirect`, you will receive `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` as header in the called App Engine project. You can trust this header, as Google would strip it off if somebody off App Engine would use it. Make sure you target the `yourproject.appspot.com` domain, as it won't work with custom domains.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/